# DOCKER: Pyspark reading from Postgresql doesn't show data

Tags: postgresql, docker, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to read data from a table in a postgresql database and proceed with an ETL project. I have an Docker enviroment using this docker-compose:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  spark-master:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3.3
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    volumes:
       - /opt/spark-apps
       - /opt/spark-data
    environment:
      - SPARK_LOCAL_IP=spark-master
      - SPARK_WORKLOAD=master
  spark-worker-a:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3.3
    ports:
      - "9091:8080"
      - "7000:7000"
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    environment:
      - SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKLOAD=worker
      - SPARK_LOCAL_IP=spark-worker-a
    volumes:
       - /opt/spark-apps
       - /opt/spark-data
  spark-worker-b:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3.3
    ports:
      - "9092:8080"
      - "7001:7000"
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    environment:
      - SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKLOAD=worker
      - SPARK_LOCAL_IP=spark-worker-b
    volumes:
        - /opt/spark-apps
        - /opt/spark-data

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres:11.7-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
    volumes:
       - /data/postgres
    ports:
      - "4560:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped

  # jupyterlab with pyspark
  jupyter-pyspark:
    image: jupyter/pyspark-notebook:latest
    environment:
      JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB: "yes"
    ports:
      - "9999:8888"
    volumes:
      - /app/data
```

I was succesful connecting to the DB, but I can't print any data. Here's my code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder\
                    .appName("salesETL")\
                    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "./postgresql-42.5.1.jar")\
                    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://postgres_container:5432/postgres")\
                              .option("dbtable", "sales")\
                              .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")\
                              .option("user", "admin")\
                              .option("password", "admin").load()

df.show(10).toPandas()
```

With `.toPandas()` it gives me this error:

```
    AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
    Cell In[7], line 1
    ----> 1 df.show(10).toPandas()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'toPandas'
```

Without `.toPandas()` it print the columns but no data

```
+--------+----------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+--------------+----------+--------+-----------+
|order_id|order_date|customer_id|customer_name|customer_lastname|customer_city|customer_state|product_id|quantity|order_value|
+--------+----------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+--------------+----------+--------+-----------+
+--------+----------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+--------------+----------+--------+-----------+
```

I am new to Pyspark/Spark so I can't figure out what I am missing. It's my very first project. What can it be?

ps: when I run `type(df)` it returns `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I couldn't find a justification of why this has happened and fix it. Instead, I took a workaround: I loaded data to Python using Pandas and then changed the pandas DF to Pyspark DF.

Here's my code:

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

appName = "salesETL"
master = "local"

spark = SparkSession.builder.master(master).appName(appName).getOrCreate()

engine = create_engine(
    "postgresql+psycopg2://admin:admin@postgres_container/postgres?client_encoding=utf8")
pdf = pd.read_sql('select * from sales.sales', engine)

# Convert Pandas dataframe to spark DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
```

Answer (score 0):

`show` returns nothing. You should call pandas on the dataframe directly. Moreover, I think it's `to_pandas` not `toPandas` (https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.to_pandas.html). So it seems the error will be vanished, with something like that:

```
df.to_pandas()
```

About the empty dataset, is there any error? If there is no error, are you sure that any records exist on the table?

Comment: Hello, Meysam! Thanks for your answer. Actually, `df.to_pandas()` returned this error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_pandas'`. And I am sure that the table is populated, I did it myself with some sample data.

Comment: `df.count()` returns `0` to me. Is my l`oad()` function correct? It seems it haven't loaded anything. But there is data in the table.

Comment: Which version of spark do you use? And can you append the result of `df.explain()` to the question?

Comment: Version: `v3.3.1` and the result of `df.explain()`: `== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Scan JDBCRelation(sales) [numPartitions=1] [order_id#0,order_date#1,customer_id#2,customer_name#3,customer_lastname#4,customer_city#5,customer_state#6,product_id#7,quantity#8,order_value#9] PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<order_id:int,order_date:date,customer_id:int,customer_name:string,customer_lastname:string...`